# highscore and keeping score

Tags: python-3.x, integer, nested-for-loop

#This is a for loop to get the score of a player playing a riddle game
#It runs and loops but it's not calculating the score properly. #There're 6 riddles and 3 rounds. #Say I get 4/6 correct my score is 20 but it's displaying 3.0 instead. how do I get a precise answer while importing the math function?

```
for i in range(6):
        print(riddles[i])  
        #
        userchoice = input("Enter A, B, C, or D: ")
        if userchoice.upper() == answers[i]:
            print("That's Correct")
            score += 5
            print(f" {score}")
        else:
            print("That's Incorrect")
            
            score -= 1
            
            print(f"{score}")

        total = total + int(score)
        
    highScoreEasy = print(f"Here is your score: {int(total/score)} !!!!!")
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it just be a simple sum?

```
riddles = []
answers = []

riddle_score = 5
total = len(riddles) * riddle_score
score = 0

for i, riddle in enumerate(riddles):
    print(riddle)

    userchoice = input("Enter A, B, C, or D: ")
    if userchoice.upper() == answers[i]:
        print("That's Correct")
        score += riddle_score
    else:
        print("That's Incorrect")

print(f"Here is your score: {score}/{total}!")
```